# what is the minumim required packages for installing open java 8

Tags: java, openjdk

What are the minimum packages required to install open java 8?

```
Available packages:
openjdk-8-dbg           openjdk-8-jdk           openjdk-8-jre-jamvm
openjdk-8-demo          openjdk-8-jre           openjdk-8-jre-zero
openjdk-8-doc           openjdk-8-jre-headless  openjdk-8-source
```

if you could give an explanation of what each package is for, that might be helpful too.

Comment: It depends. What do you want to do with Java? Or why do you need to install Java?

Comment: well, the obvious answer is to run java programs like minecraft... however, creating java apps will be good too.

Comment: `openjdk-8-jre` is enough for minecraft for developing you need the jdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- For software development:

  OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK)

  ```
  sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
  ```
- To start Java applications

  OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT

  ```
  sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre
  ```
- Other packages:

  - openjdk-8-dbg

    This package contains the debugging symbols.
  - openjdk-8-demo

    Java runtime based on OpenJDK (demos and examples)
  - openjdk-8-doc

    OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK) documentation
  - openjdk-8-jre-headless

    OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT (headless)
  - openjdk-8-jre-jamvm

    Alternative JVM for OpenJDK, using JamVM
  - openjdk-8-jre-zero

    Alternative JVM for OpenJDK, using Zero/Shark
  - openjdk-8-source

    OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK) source files

Answer (score 2):

Short answer:

Generally `JDK` is suitable for **any** cases, so if you don't know what to install - simply install `JDK`.

---

`openjdk-8-dbg`

Package that consists bring [debugging symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debug_symbol). Debug symbols come with JDK by default, but sometimes you have to install them separately.

---

`openjdk-8-demo`

Package that consists of demos and examples. This package bring some sources with `README` that explain examples.

---

`openjdk-8-doc`

Package that consists of Java documentation. This package is also comes with `JDK` by default.

---

`openjdk-8-jdk`

Package that consists of `JDK` - [Java Development Kit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Development_Kit). If you want to develop java applications you need this package. Otherwise you probably need `JRE`.

---

`openjdk-8-jre`

Package that consists of `JRE` - Java Runtime Environment. The Java Runtime Environment (JRE), also known as Java Runtime, is part of the Java Development Kit (JDK), a set of programming tools for developing Java applications. The Java Runtime Environment provides the minimum requirements for executing a Java application; it consists of the Java Virtual Machine (JVM), core classes, and supporting files [[source]](http://searchsoa.techtarget.com/definition/Java-Runtime-Environment).

---

`openjdk-8-jre-headless`

Package that consists of `JRE`, but package does not provide dependencies used for the graphical components.

---

`openjdk-8-jre-jamvm`

Package that consists of JRE with [`JAMVM` virtual machine](http://jamvm.sourceforge.net/). JamVM is an open-source Java Virtual Machine that aims to support the latest version of the JVM specification, while at the same time being compact and easy to understand.

---

`openjdk-8-jre-zero`

Package that consists of `JRE` with ported `JVM`, this port called [zero-assembler Hotspot (or zero).](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IcedTea#Platform_support)

---

`openjdk-8-source`

Package that consists of `OpenJDK` source code. OpenJDK is a development environment for building applications, applets, and components using the Java programming language.  This package contains the Java programming language source files (src.zip) for all classes that make up the Java core API [[source]](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/vivid/+package/openjdk-8-source).